# Display counting variable in for

Tags: php, for-loop, count

So I'm trying to learn PHP..

```html
    <form action="momo.php" method="post">

        <label for="number1">Repeat:</label>
        <input type="text" name="number1">  <br>
        <label for="text1">Text:</label>
        <input type="text" name="text1"> <br>

        <input type="submit" name="send">

    </form>
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['number1'])) {

    $number1= $_POST['number1'];
    $text1= $_POST['text1'];

        if(is_numeric($number1)) {

            echo "Numerical!<br><br>";

            for($i=0;$i<$number1;$i++) {
            echo $text1;
            }

        }
            else {
            echo "Not numerical!";          
            }
}
```

..and I've managed to make this work! I cannot make it count each result though, I've tried with the `count()` but I'm not sure how to use it, and I can only find how to use it for arrays.

If I enter this:

- Repeat: 3
- Text: Hi!

It'll look like this:

> ```
> Hi!
> Hi!
> Hi!
> ```

Though I want it to look like this:

> ```
> 1 Hi!
> 2 Hi!
> 3 Hi!
> ```

Comment: Just do `echo $i.' '.$text1;` then? The code looks fine otherwise

Comment: Quick note: `<label for>` attribute should reference an *ID*, not a *name*. However, you can just do `<label>Text <input /></label>` to have the label automatically apply to the input - much easier!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That's a typo, translated it and shortened it so it would all make more sense to you all and failed there.. He he :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for($i=0;$i<$number1;$i++) {
    echo $i+1.' '.$text1;
}
```

Or

```
for($i=1;$i<=$number1;$i++) {
    echo $i.' '.$text1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
for($i=1;$i<$number1;$i++) {
    echo $i.' '.$text1;
}
```

Comment: for($i=1;$i<=$number1;$i++) {
    echo $i.' '.$text1;
}

Answer (score 0):

Cool that you're trying to learn PHP.

This should fix your issue.

```
for($i=1;$i<$number1;$i++) {
    echo $1.' '.$text1;
}
```

Defining the first parameter in a for loop can be confusing.

Hope it helps! 
Cheers

Comment: $i<$number1 with a = in between < and $ made it work correctly, thanks!